# SAP BO Deski Query Panel - Classes and Objects panel not visible

Tags: class, panel, business-objects, visible

I'm using SAP BO Desktop Intelligence v12.1.0.882, on a Windows workstation with limited privileges.

**Issue:**
After opening an existing report template (.rep) file, and clicking on the button for "Edit Data Provider", the Query Panel does not display the "Classes and Objects" pane on the left.

When clicking on the button for "Show/hide all classes" in top left of query pane, it does not show / have any effect on what is displayed in the Query Panel for "Classes and Objects".

**What I've tried:**

1) I've read through the "Business Objects User's Guide: Accessing Data and Data Analysis" (Business Objects 6.1), eg page 57, but this doesn't cover / mention this issue.

2) Searches via Google and Bing, however these do not give many relevant results.

**Ideas:**

1) Possibly viewing what rights on what DeskI can and can't show to me?

Comment: I don't believe there's a Right that covers that; and if there was, I would think that you wouldn't even see the button.  But to rule it out, I would try logging into DeskI as Administrator.  Do you get the same behavior with every universe?

Comment: @Joe. Thanks - this is now resolved - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved.

Resolution was to drag the left pane across using the cursor :).